# Is the set of norming vectors weakly closed?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, inequalities, sobolev-spaces

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a separable Hilbert space, let $p\ge 2$, and consider a bounded linear operator 
$
T\colon \mathcal{H}\to L^p(\mathbb R^d). $

> Is the set $M=\{f\in \mathcal H\ :\ \|Tf\|_{L^p}= \|T\|\|f\|_{\mathcal H}\}$ closed in the weak topology of $\mathcal H$?

Here $\|T\|= \sup\{ \|Tf\|_{L^p}\ :\ \|f\|_{\mathcal{H}}=1\}$. Note that $M$ is always norm closed.

---

**Motivation**. This idea comes from Sobolev embeddings.

As a simple example, let $T$ be the identity mapping $T\colon H^1(\mathbb R)\to L^\infty(\mathbb R)$, where $\|f\|_{H^1}^2=\|f\|_{L^2}^2+\|f'\|_{L^2}^2$. In this case, letting $f_{y}(x):=e^{-|x-y|}$, it [turns out that](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2329594/8157)
$$
M=\{ af_{y}\ |\ a\in\mathbb R,\ y\in\mathbb R\}. $$
This set is weakly closed in $H^1(\mathbb R)$. Indeed, if the sequence $a_nf_{y_n}$ converges weakly, then it is bounded, and so $a_n$ must be bounded. If $y_n\in\mathbb R$ is also bounded, then we can extract a strongly convergent subsequence and we are done; if $y_n$ is not bounded, then $a_n f_{y_n}\rightharpoonup 0$, and $0\in M$.

The same reasoning applies to the embedding $H^1(\mathbb R^d) \subset L^p(\mathbb R^d)$, where $p=2d/(d-2)$. In this case, $M$ is the set of all translates and dilates of $f(x)=(1+|x|^2)^{-\frac{d}p}$.

*Remark*. If $p=2$, then $M$ is a closed subspace of $\mathcal H$, and so it is weakly closed. Indeed, since $\lVert Tf\rVert_{L^2}=\langle T^\ast Tf| f\rangle$, $M$ is exactly the eigenspace of $T^\ast T$ corresponding to its dominant eigenvalue. The fact that there is a dominant eigenvalue is a consequence of the boundedness of $T$, hence of $T^\ast T$.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to share some of my thoughts on the problem. I think that the proposition is too hard to prove, and maybe it is even false, at this level of generality. However, there is an assumption on $T$ that makes the proposition true: it is the following *Brezis-Lieb property* (refers to Lemma 2.6 of [Lieb](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2007032), Sharp constants in the Hardy-Littlewood-Sobolev and related inequalities, Annals of Mathematics 1983).

**Property**. We say that $T$ satisfies the *Brezis-Lieb property* if, for all $g_n\in M$ such that $g_n\rightharpoonup g$, it holds that
$$\tag{1}\|Tg_n\|_p^p =\|Tg\|_p^p+\|T(g_n-g)\|_p^p+o(1).$$

**Proposition**. Let $\Omega$ be a measure space, let $p>2$, and suppose that the bounded operator $T\colon \mathcal H\to L^p(\Omega)$ satisfies the Brezis-Lieb property. Then $M$ is weakly closed.

*Proof*. Let $g_n\in M$, $g_n\rightharpoonup g$, and denote $r_n:=g-g_n$. Since $g_n\rightharpoonup g$ we have 
$$\tag{2} \|g_n\|_{\mathcal H}^2  = \|g\|_{\mathcal H}^2 + \|r_n\|_{\mathcal H}^2 + \epsilon_n, $$ 
where $\epsilon_n\to 0$. Since $g_n\in M$, by the Brezis-Lieb property we have 
$$
\tag{3} \begin{split}\|T\|^p\|g_n\|_{\mathcal H}^p&=\|Tg_n\|_p^p= \|Tg\|_p^p + \|Tr_n\|_p^p + \eta_n \\ 
&\le \|T\|^p\|g\|_{\mathcal H}^p + \|T\|^p \|r_n\|_{\mathcal H}^p + \eta_n,\end{split} $$ 
where $\eta_n\to 0$. Now, since $p>2$, for all $a\ne 0, b\ne 0$ we have the strict inequality $a^p+b^p <(a^2+b^2)^{p/2}$. So, assuming that all sequences converge, as we may up to a subsequence as they are all bounded, we have 
$$
\|T\|^p\lim \|g_n\|_{\mathcal H}^p < (\|T\|^2\|g\|_{\mathcal H}^2 + \|T\|^2\lim\|r_n\|_{\mathcal H}^2)^\frac{p}{2}=\|T\|^p\lim \|g_n\|_{\mathcal H}^p,$$
where we used (2) in the last identity, provided that both $\|g\|_{\mathcal H}\ne 0 $ and $\lim\|r_n\|_{\mathcal H}\ne 0$. This is clearly a contradiction.

We conclude one of $\|g\|_{\mathcal H}$ and $\lim\|r_n\|_{\mathcal H}$ must vanish. If that's $\|g\|_{\mathcal H}$, that means $g_n\rightharpoonup 0$. If that's $\lim\|r_n\|_{\mathcal H}$, that means $g_n\to g$ strongly in $\mathcal H$. In both cases, $g\in M$. $\Box$

*Remarks*.

1. This is the standard subadditivity argument used to prove the existence of extremizers; see for example Lemma 2.7 in the aforementioned paper of Lieb.
2. The Brezis-Lieb property is a kind of compactness assumption on $T$. All compact operators trivially satisfy it, because $g_n\rightharpoonup g$ implies $Tg_n\to Tg$ strongly. Less trivially, all Sobolev embeddings satisfy the Brezis-Lieb property. Indeed, if $T\colon H^s\to L^p$ is the identity mapping, by the Rellich compactness theorem a sequence $g_n\stackrel{H^s}{\rightharpoonup} g$ converges $L^2$-strongly on balls, and so it converges pointwise almost everywhere; and now, if $g_n\to g$ almost everywhere, then (1) is satisfied by the standard Brezis-Lieb lemma. As far as I understand, this very idea has been used by Fanelli, Vega and Visciglia to study maximizers for inequalities in harmonic analysis: see [1](https://academic.oup.com/blms/article-abstract/43/4/811/259969?redirectedFrom=fulltext) and [2](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0001870811004105).
3. If $g_n\rightharpoonup g$ then $Tg_n\rightharpoonup Tg$, which, however, is not enough to conclude the Brezis-Lieb property (1). [This paper of Adimurthi and Tintarev](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00030-015-0333-2) gives sufficient conditions for the Brezis-Lieb property to be satisfied with weak convergence alone.

Comment: [Link to similar "proximinal" maps in convex analysis](https://mathoverflow.net/q/262851/13042).